# How to know when isolated storage is being deleted in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight app that uses IsolatedStorage to store some info about the current session.

If the user right clicks the mouse and chooses Silverlight and goes to delete the application storage, I get an exception of type IsolatedStorageException when I call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite().

I don't want to use try-catch block to catch the exception, I just want to be able to call the method successfully, or a similar method like the one above.

Is there a way to know (maybe an event) when user deletes the application storage? I use Silverlight 4.0.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

They are no events that you can use to determine whether the user has done that action.

The best you can do is use an error handler and display a message to the user, perhaps politely pointing out that one *possible* cause might be the deletion of a site storage.

According to the documentation unless the user has disabled or set set the quota to 0 the call should succeed but I wouldn't be surprise if SL doesn't like it.